# How to retrieve an objects attribute information from within an array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to get the speed of a car object. Actually of all cars stored in an array and then pass that value to another variable.

So heres an example of what I  have:

```
public class Car
{
    private int speed;

    public Car(int s)
    {
        speed = s;
    }

    public int getSpeed()
    {
        return speed;
    }
    public void setSpeed(int s)
    {
        speed = s;
    }
}
```

I have a class that creates an array of cars.

```
public class Environment {

private Car[] garage;   
private Random random;


public Environment(){
    random = new Random();
    populateGarage();
}

public void populateGarage()
{
    garage = new Car[4];
    int randomSpeed;
    Car car;

    for(int i= 0; i < garage.length; i++)
    {
        randomSpeed = random.nextInt(10);
        if(randomSpeed < 5){
            randomSpeed = randomSpeed +5;
        }
        car = new Car(carNames[i], randomSpeed);
        garage.add(car);

        System.out.println("car has speed "+ car.getSpeed());
    }
```

All works fine up to this point. Now I am trying to access that value in a different class. Here's an example:

```
public class RaceDisplay extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

   private int velX;
   private int x;
   private Car car;
   private Environment env;


public RaceDisplay(){

        x=0;
        velX=env.getArray[0]... (the velocity value should be one of the car's speeds) <-------------
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        super.paintComponent(g);
      //  (....)

    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

       x=x+velX;
           if(x>=650){
           x=0;
           x=x+velX; 
  }
}
```

I'm stuck on how to access that information through another class. Any help is most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because `garage` is a private field you will need a getter function set up in `Environment`

```
public Car getGarage (int index) {
    return garage [index];
}
```

Of course if you are not interested in the `Car` object at all and just want the speed you could write a method to that like:

```
public int getSpeedOfCar (int index) {
    return garage [index].getSpeed ();
}
```

Comment: So a getter in the environment class?